# git pre-push hook script not running after changing config

Tags: git

I created a script .git/hooks/pre-push and set the config using git config core.hooksPath .git/hooks/pre-push and it worked fine after setting chmod.

But, as you might know, this file cannot be committed to the repo so I create a .mygithooks/pre-push in my repo's top level and committed it.

Then set the git config core.hooksPath to .mygithooks/pre-push and set chmod but this time the script stopped working. I removed the one from .git/hooks/pre-push just to be sure and it still didn't work.

then I deleted the ./myhooks/pre-push and put the script back to the original .git/hooks/pre-push and then git config core.hooksPath and then chmod and now this one stopped working too.

What did I do wrong?

ps: I have an "echo" in the first line of the script. It also prints a bunch of stuff when it runs so it's not that the script runs successfully and silently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`core.hooksPath` is a directory name, not a file name.  You need to specify a directory, like `.mygithooks`.

Do note that using hooks from inside the repository is a security risk: anyone who can cause code to be committed to your repository can execute arbitrary code on your machine.  You should therefore not use such a configuration unless you are the only one with access to this repository.

Comment: oops. that was it. spent an hour trying to debug. haha